# Giving Exceptions to a Random Choice

Tags: python

Now I have been trying for fun to make my own version of the game clue, and I cannot seem to find out how do this. I am trying to make it so that if the guess is wrong, it will give a hint from the other guesses that is not the real "killer" and that is not any of their previous guesses. I'll give an example of something similar:

```
    a = input()
    b = input()
    c = input()
    d = input()
    e = input()
    f = input()
    hint = random.choice([a,b,c,d,e,f])
    hint != killer
    hint != previous_guess
```

Now I know that the hint != killer and hint != previous_guess doesn't really do anything, as hint is assigned before. I am wondering if there is any way to make it so that it will chose randomly from a variable that is not the killer or a previous guess. Thanks in advance! Oh also I would like to point out that I am using python.

Comment: If `a` through to `f` are the player's guesses, then your code currently asks for six guesses, picks one of those guesses at random, and makes `hint != killer` evaluate to `True` if that randomly selected guess is *not* the killer. Is this what you thought it did? If not, what were you hoping to achieve?

Comment: I was hoping to make it later that if the player does not guess the correct killer, it would make a print statement along the lines of:
print ("*Hint, the killer is not " + hint + ".")
Now, that hint cannot be the real killer obviously, and I do not want it to be a previous guess. Is there any way that I can make it so that the program will chose randomly from all the other choices except the real killer and a previous guess.

Comment: Oh also I see what else you were asking. At the beginning I allow the player to customize the names for the possible killers, which is inputted in a through f. Then from that I had previously randomly selected the real killer (I did not show it all in here to keep the code short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a set and subtract the ones you dont want, e.g.

```
hint = random.choice(list({a, b, c, d, e, f} - {killer, previous_guess}))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was thinking, I knew there had to be an easy way to do it but I was at a mindblank.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic way you could do it. This uses the concept of what is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) in order to generate a list in an efficient way. The `.format()` indicates string formatting, which allows you to pass variables into strings in a variety of formats (docs [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), but for now just know that `{0}` refers to the first argument to `format()`).

`names` is generated using the aforementioned list comprehension, and it is syntactically equivalent to:

```
names = []
for i in range(6):
    names.append(raw_input('Enter a name: ')
```

This pattern is used later to generate your list without the killer nor the previous guess. Happy to explain any parts that don't make sense (thanks to @JonClements for pointing out some oddness I had left in there):

```
import random


# Choose your names
names = [raw_input('Enter killer name: ') for i in xrange(6)]

# Choose a killer
killer = random.choice(names)

# Run for as many times as you want (here we do 6; could also be len(names)
max_guesses = 6

for guessno in xrange(max_guesses):
  guess = raw_input('Guess the killer: ')
  # If the guess is not the killer...
  if guess != killer:
    # This line creates a list that does not include the killer nor the guess
    hint = random.choice([n for n in names if n not in [killer, guess]])
    print 'Hint, the killer is not {0}'.format(hint)
  else:
    print 'Correct! The killer is {0}'.format(guess)
    break
```

Comment: This works too, thanks for the quick reply and good suggestion! It also showed me all the needless writing I do, this is much more compressed.

Comment: @GafRiedS Right on, happy it helped!

Comment: A couple of bits (that I couldn't post last night due to SO going into read-only mode!): `guesses` is never incremented (ergo infinite loop missing a correct guess), but you'd be better off re-writing it as `for guess_no in xrange(max_guesses)` anyway. `hint` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere...  `killer`/`guess` what-not are going to be strings, so your list-comp should be `[n for n in names if n not in [killer, guess]]`

Comment: @JonClements Ha, totally agree - I blame the read-only mode for the errant copy/pasting! I was erring more on the side of a basic example of list comprehensions while trying to be explicit (I wasn't sure of the level of the OP), so I thought that the `not in` in the `hint` list comp may be easier to understand (but since I'm not the best teacher, I do agree that your correct way is actually easier to understand as well :) ). As for the `while` loop, no excuses there - that was just a bad call :)

Comment: @JonClements I'll update for posterity's sake now, thanks for the input!